# facebook Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

facebook like button in my website was working great for maybe 1 month yesterday i found it broken

i check it by facebook debug tool it gives me: 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmezo.me%2F

So any one know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

meta tag is missing , use something like below

```
  <meta property="og:type"       content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"        content="http://womenwants.me/chat1/" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"      content="Fun Group Chat" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"      content="http://www.rijewelers.com/product_images/uploaded_images/chat-icon.jpg" />
```

Comment: how and where i add that
<pre></style></head><body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); function likeme(){ if (typeof parent.click_callback == 'function') setTimeout('parent.click_callback("<?=$sit['id']?>", "<?=$sit['cpc']?>")',1000); } FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',likeme); 
</script>
<fb:like href="<?=$sit['facebook']?>" send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
</body>
</html><?}?><code>